# Python Search File and Store as Variable

Tags: python, http, full-text-search

I am looking to get my program to use a HTTP GET to read information about my smart devices.

I want to search this for "name" and then put "corner light" into an array.

```
{
"1": {
    "state": {
        "on": true,
        "bri": 114,
        "alert": "none",
        "reachable": true
    },
    "type": "Dimmable light",
    "name": "corner light",
    "modelid": "LWB010",
    "manufacturername": "Philips",
},
```

Comment: Why do you have to "search"? JSON is a well-defined format, and presumably so is the output of whatever this HTTP endpoint is you're planning on GETting. Just `import json; json.loads()` it - or use Python Requests which handles JSON natively.

Comment: Please add a relevant json for example

Comment: Apologies, added.